# How can QDir::makeAbsolute() fail?

Tags: qt, path, qdir

The documentation for `QDir::makeAbsolute()` says

> Converts the directory path to an absolute path. If it is already absolute nothing happens. Returns `true` if the conversion succeeded; otherwise returns `false`.

It's not clear to me how the creation of an absolute path from a relative path could fail.

Of course there's no guarantee that a directory will actually exist at that absolute path, but for the most part the `QDir` API doesn't concern itself with whether the directory exists or not, so I'd be surprised if that was what it was doing here.

Answer (score 2):

[`QDir::makeAbsolute`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qdir.cpp.html#_ZN4QDir12makeAbsoluteEv) returns `false` (fails) if for some reason the file engine returns a relative path when asked for an absolute one:

```
QString absolutePath = d->fileEngine->fileName(QAbstractFileEngine::AbsoluteName);
if (QDir::isRelativePath(absolutePath))
    return false;
```

Comment: That's how far I got in my own research. I'm still curious about how or why that might happen.

Comment: @ParkerCoates, why did not you bother to mention that in your question then? That could have spared my time digging in the source code.

Comment: fair enough. I only thought to check the source code after I had posted the question, but I should have come back and edited it.